# how necessary is it to xss_clean data fetched from database over network?

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter, xml-rpc

Currently i am working on xmlrpc library of codeigniter.
we are fetching data from delphi to xmlrpc where it is being proceesed by xmlrpc.
But on debugging i found that **xmlrpc is taking too much time in processing data and half of the that time is being consumed by xss_clean .**
there is one method Decode which is cleaning(xss_cleaning) the data in codeigniter xmlrpc 1.7 .
**my question is can we remove that xss_clean part as it is consuming lots of time ?**
**is it a good practice to xss_clean the database output received over newtwork ?**
is there any alternate to optimize xmlrpc processing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [CodeIgniter Documentation on XMLRPC](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/xmlrpc.html) states:

> There are two additional configuration keys you may make use of when
>   initializing the server class: debug can be set to TRUE in order to
>   enable debugging, and xss_clean may be set to FALSE to prevent sending
>   data through the Security library's xss_clean function.

If you trust the source, then don't bother with xss.

∴ Use: `$config['xss_clean'] = FALSE;`

Comment: Currently i am also testing my application with the same settings i.e by making xss_clean=FALSE .
But my main concern is that will it be fine to do so?
Data which i am populating is from known resource and it is clean and not malicious.

Comment: You said it yourself - if its known to be not malicious, turn it off :)

Comment: I mean it is not malicious intentionally.but is it possible that it get affected by illegal characters during transmission.communication between database machine and web server is over LAN.

Comment: Sorry. I don't know. That warrants a new question.

Comment: Thanks Jordan for your suggestions :)

Comment: My pleasure. Please click the checkmark next to my answer if you feel it has helped you. Thanks!